# How to set <select>'s height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select, height

I can't seem to be able to define a height for a `<select>` even setting it to `display:block`

```
select{
    height: 100px; /* ignored */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Vz9Y/

Any idea why?

-edit-

I am using google chrome

Comment: it's working for me.  What browser are you using

Comment: Better to use `padding: 40px 0;`. The text does not center in FireFox. The height is working in Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: Which version, which platform?

Comment: try using developer tools and inspect the element to see if any other css is being applied to it

Comment: Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/3Vz9Y/3/

Comment: in chrome its working perfect

Comment: which version of Chrome?  Have you tried updating? Working fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Also you may style your `select` by this way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vz9Y/5/)

```
.styled{
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    -webkit-appearance: none;    
    height: 25px;
    min-width: 50px;   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a Mac, make sure to put

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
```

above the styling attributes, eg:

```
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 100px;
display: inline-block;
```

}

Then you can style to your hearts content.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Vz9Y/17/

Comment: Apologies, JunM has answered this correctly, I should learn to read answers before answering - sorry about that JunM

Answer (score -2):

Try this Code..

Now this code works in all browsers...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vz9Y/16/)

CSS

```
 select
    {
    min-height:20px;
    display: block;
    }
```

Html

```
<select>
     <option>hi</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: I think, this still ignore the `height`.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet is the select tag wrapped in to some other tag??? or you are having the<Select> tag alone?? is the fiddle demo working fine for you?? or you are having issue in fiddle too??

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work for me, and of corse is wrapped with other tag, I don't have any body with just a select ;)